# Creating Generic Collection within a collection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I have two classes and want to build a collection that contains a collection. Thus I have..

```
public class GenericReportInfo 
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ReportFileName { get; set; }
    public Paramaters parameterList { get; set; }
}

public class Paramaters 
{
    public List<string> parameter { get; set; }

}
```

And want to get to the point where I can simply add to the collection inline ie

```
public class GenericReportsInfo
{
   public List<GenericReportInfo> CreateAndInitialize()
   {
       List<GenericReportInfo> reportsList = new List<GenericReportInfo>();
       GenericReportInfo info = new GenericReportInfo() 
         { "Agent", "Agent", new paramter() {"StateId"} };

       return reportsList;
   }
}
```

Just would like know the correct way to get to this.

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
List<GenericReportInfo> reportsList = new List<GenericReportInfo>();
GenericReportInfo info = new GenericReportInfo()
{
    ReportName = "Agent",
    ReportFileName = "Agent",
    parameterList = new Paramaters() { parameter = new List<string> { "StateId" } }
};
```

I'd like to add a few comments, though:

- It should be Param**e**ters, not Param**a**ters.
- I would capitalize **P**arameterList as well (like the other public properties).
- Unless you expect the Parameters class to contain more fields in the future, I'm not sure if it's worth to have an extra class for this (just to encapsulate a `List<String>`).

Answer (score 1):

Heinzi's answer is correct. But just for completeness, you could also create a constructor that takes the standard fields as well as a param array of your Parameter type. If your class is small it can be a cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a list of strings you could have a list of parameters instead...

```
public class GenericReportInfo 
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ReportFileName { get; set; }
    public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public GenericReportInfo(
        string reportName,
        string reportFileName,
        IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        ReportName = reportName;
        ReportFileName = reportFileName;
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>(parameters);
    }
}

public class Parameter 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then to initialise...

```
GenericReportInfo info = new GenericReportInfo()
{
    ReportName = "Agent",
    ReportFileName = "Agent",
    Parameters = new List<Parameter>() { new Parameter(){ Name = "StateId" } }
};
```